# Compare percentages for a progress-bar in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, progress-bar

I am making a `progress bar` in PHP, when calling the data from ajax I have an error when the value is 6% it indicates a warning, and when it is 8% it indicates danger, but if it is the value it is in the range of 1 to 5% or more than 10% is a success.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#value').text(data);
                    $('.progress-bar').css('width', data+'%');
                    if (data+'%' <= '50%')
                        {
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-sucess");
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-warning");
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-danger");
                            $('.progress-bar').addClass("bg-sucess");
                        }
                    else if (data+'%' == '51%' || data+'%' <= '70%')
                        {
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-sucess");
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-warning");
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-danger");
                            $('.progress-bar').addClass("bg-warning");
                        }
                    else if (data+'%' >= '71%' || data+'%' <= '100%')
                        {
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-sucess");
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-warning");
                            $('.progress-bar').removeClass("bg-danger");
                            $('.progress-bar').addClass("bg-danger");
                        }
                }
            });
```

It only happens in these cases from 6 to 9%, if it is less than 50 or greater than 70 if it complies.

Can you help me ?

Comment: (data+'%' <= '50%') you are comparing a string instead of a number try data <= 50 instead.

Comment: I understand, I am going to correct my code and test.